# Storing a homogenous delimited list in sql database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am trying to model a "retail store" in a relational database.
A store has

1. A unique Id
2. An owner Id
3. It may have multiple outlets
4. All outlets of a store will have the same owner.
5. All the outlets of a store may or may not have the same products. There maybe some products available in one outlet which may not be available in another outlet of the same retail store.

My tables

```
Products
  productId*
  productPrice
  fooAndBars

Store
  outletId*
  ownerId
  fooAndBars

productStoreJoin
  productId        \__Primary key
  ownerId          /
```

My problem:

There maybe some products available in one outlet which may not be in another.
To get all the products of an outlet, I will query the join table. But I will get all the products even if its not available in that outlet, since I will be querying with ownerId.

The solutions what i could come up with:

1. Use outletId instead of ownerId in the join table. But, there will be around 1000 products in an outlet and a store may have around 100 outlets, which amounts to 10^5 rows in the join table for a single store!
   Using ownerId in the join table thus reduces it to 1000 rows!
2. Add another column in the join table "outletIds" which will be a comma separated list of outletIds which will have the list of outlets which have that product. So it will look like this -

---

```
productId ownerId        outletIds
```

---

```
   56      2      [1001, 1005, 1008, 1009]

   57      2      [1001, 1005, 1008]
```

...

What should be the correct approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely #1. If you need to know which products are available in which outlets, you should have a join table that maps products to outlets. It's expected for this table to have a lot of rows and 10^5 rows for one store is fine. MySQL is very fast with join queries that use integer values. In keeping with your naming convention, I would rename the join table to `productOutletJoin`.

Your #2 approach would be a nightmare for queries as simple as "which products are in outlet 1008?" And imagine trying to insert, update, or delete data with that schema. Storing comma-separated lists of ids is never a good idea.